# Is there a way to pass detached object to JPA persist? (detached entity passed to persist)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have 2 entities : `Account` and `AccountRole`.

```
public class Account {
   private AccountRole accountRole;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   public AccountRole getAccountRole() {
      return accountRole;
   }
```

.

```
public class AccountRole {
    private Collection<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountRole", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Collection<Account> getAccounts() {
         return accounts;
    }
```

Problem comes when I take the accountRole from database and try to persist my `Account`. **At this point I just created my account and role already exists in db.**

```
AccountRole role = accountService.getRoleFromDatabase(AccountRoles.ROLE_USER);
account.setAccountRole(role);

//setting both ways, as suggested
public void setAccountRole(AccountRole accountRole) {
    accountRole.addAccount(this);
    this.accountRole = accountRole;
}

entityManager.persist(account); // finally in my DAO
```

I read this : [JPA/Hibernate: detached entity passed to persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist) **And what I understood, I must set the entities values from both direction, so that what I am doing in my setter.**

Still getting error.

```
 org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: foo.bar.pojo.AccountRole
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just replace the

```
entityManager.persist(account);
```

with:

```
entityManager.merge(account);
```

And allow merge cascading:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public AccountRole getAccountRole() {
    return accountRole;
}
```

Because merge does this:

> If your entity is new, it's the same as a persist().
>   But if your entity already exists, it will update it.

Comment: Also note that, `persist()` will make the object you passed a managed entity, however, merge will return a managed copy of the object of you passed. So if you need a managed entity after merge you should do `account = entityManager.merge(account)` Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1070629/1260908)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you leave the transaction during your processing, so the `accountRole` gets detached, or it is already detached for other reasons.

A  call to `entityManager.merge(accountRole)` before calling `entityManager.persist(account)` should fix it.

EDIT: Unfortunately, if you cannot be sure if the `accountRole` already exists in the DB, you will have to check it by querying. If it exists - merge, if not - persist. It is indeed a hassle, but I have not yet seen a better workaround.

EDIT2: The entity you pass to the `merge` method will remain detached - the managed entity will be returned by the `merge`, so you would need to merge first, then set the reference on the `account` to the return value of the `merge`.

Comment: in rare occasions the `AccountRole` does not exist in database, so when doing `em.persist`, it persists the account and accountrole, and everything works. now when I find myself in that case with your code, it is trying to add the `AccountRole` twice to database, first with merge, with succeedes and then with persist also, thus giving me `duplicate key value violation error`, any suggestions? problem is that, sometimes the role does not exist.

Comment: one solution could be that, if `Role` does not exist, `persist` the whole damn thing, but if role does exist, `merge` it first, but that seems like too much of a hassle, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jaanus - alas, you are correct :) I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: just tried that, same thing..   `entityManager.merge(account.getAccountRole());
  entityManager.persist(account);`  and same error : `detached entity passed to persist: ee.sellin.vahvagame.pojo.AccountRole` .. oh boy

Comment: @Jaanus - there is a quirk in JPA with merging - I forgot to mention it, sorry. See second edit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a datached entity to persist, there is no way. But you don't need to.

You want to persist an `Account` independently of the `AccountRole`(which is already persisted). In order to achieve this, simply **remove cascading from `@ManyToOne` in the child entity** (`Account` in this case):

```
public class Account {
    private AccountRole accountRole;

    @ManyToOne // no cascading here!
    public AccountRole getAccountRole() {
        return accountRole;
    }
```

See my explanation here, why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54271569/522578