# Is it normal for JPA to return detached instances for @MapsId field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

### Summary

I'am very suprised by the behaviour I'm seeing with the following code:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class SuiviDao {


    public Suivi getSuivi(SuiviPK pk) {
        final Suivi suivi = em.find(Suivi.class, pk);
        assert em.contains(suivi);
        // throws occasionally an assertion error
        assert em.contains(suivi.getCommune());
        return suivi;
    }
}
```

I would expect having managed entities returned by the `find` method call.
This is always the case for the returned `suivi`.
However, it happens that the `commune` instance is not managed.
Is it normal JPA behaviour? Or is it something specific to Hibernate (I'm using version 4.3.7) ?

---

### Details

There is a simple workaround (see below):

```
  if (!em.contains(suivi.getCommune())) {
      final Commune commune = em.find(Commune.class, suivi.getCommune().getId());
      suivi.setCommune(commune);
  }
```

---

By digging further, I found that in the case were a non-managed Commune entity is returned, the entity is not loaded from the DB, but from Hibernate's session cache.

---

Relevant part of the related classes:

```
@Entity
public class Suivi {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SuiviPK pk = new SuiviPK();

    @MapsId("commune")
    @ManyToOne
    private Commune commune;

    @MapsId("echeance")
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private Echeance echeance;

    // remaining of class body
}

@Embeddable
public class SuiviPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ECHEANCE")
    private Long echeance;

    @Column(name = "COMMUNE")
    private Long commune;

    // remaining of class body
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that without assertions enabled, the error raised is the same as in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist).

Comment: All objects returned by find() should be in managed state, as per the spec.