# Error to save object using CascadeType.ALL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I always save a Impost before try to save Product.

I can save the Impost, but when I try to save Product (that has Impost) it fails.

My entities are like this:

```
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
private long id;

@NotNull(message = "Name cant be null")
@Size(min = 1, message = "Name must have at least one char!")
private String name;

@NotNull(message = "Price cant be null")
private Double price;

@NotNull(message = "Type cant be null")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Impost impost;

}
```

And the entity for Impost is like this:

```
public class Impost {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull(message = "The impost has a name!")
@Size(min = 1)
private String name;

@NotNull(message = "The impost percent is not null!")
private BigDecimal percent;
}
```

This is the request I do to impost:

```
{
    "name": "impost",
    "percent": "50"
}
```

This is the request I do to Product:

```
{
"name": "prod",
"price": "10",
"impost": { "id": 1 }
}
```

But I always get this error:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.tax.entity.Impost`

Comment: whats the exception or error you are facing? , add that to question

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist

Comment: I could not find the perfect solution for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause if the issue is that you are not using a managed `Impost` instance when persisting the product.

Set a managed one after you deserialize the product before persisting it:

```
product.setImpost(entityManager.getReference(product.getImpost().getId()))
```

Comment: That's correct, but I also had to change my annotation to fetch = FetchType.EAGER. Thank you!