# Hibernate "object references an unsaved transient instance"

Tags: java, hibernate

My `User`s are in `Organisation`s in a `ManyToOne` relationship, when a user is created with an existing Organisation I am trying to assign it to it without creating a new one.

In my service, here is how I create a user:

```
@Override
public UserInfo createUser(UserInfo newUser) {
    // Check if organisation exists
    OrganisationEntity orga = organisationDao.findByName(newUser.getOrganisation());

    if (orga != null) {
        // Organisation exists, we save it with the correct ID
        return mapper.map(userDao.save(mapper.map(newUser, orga.getId())));
    } else {
        // Organisation does NOT exists, we save it and create a new one
        return mapper.map(userDao.save(mapper.map(newUser, (long) -1)));
    }
}
```

With my `Mapper` (helping me to convert a model to an entity) being:

```
 public UserEntity map(UserInfo userInfo, Long orgaId) {
    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    user.setEmail(userInfo.getEmail());
    user.setFirstName(userInfo.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(userInfo.getLastName());
    user.setPassword(userInfo.getPassword());

    OrganisationEntity orga = new OrganisationEntity();
    orga.setName(userInfo.getOrganisation());

    // We set the organisation's ID
    if (orgaId != -1)
       orga.setId(orgaId);
    user.setOrganisation(orga);
    return user;
}
```

And here is my `UserDao`:

```
@Transactional
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    UserEntity save(UserEntity user);  
}
```

And finally the relation in my `UserEntity`:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = OrganisationEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "orga_id")
private OrganisationEntity organisation;
```

Creating a user with a new Organisation work but when I input an existing one, I get the following:

> detached entity passed to persist

From my [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist) it is a bidirectional consistency problem, but the answers did not help me so far.

Finally here are my Entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = OrganisationEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "orga_id")
    private OrganisationEntity organisation;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organisation")
public class OrganisationEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "orga_id", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Comment: why not let hibernate do the mapping for you? you can use annotations on your classes and for inserting use `session.save();` method. no need to implement it by yourself.

Comment: Could you please develop in an answer? It's not very clear to me.

Comment: post code of your classes. then i can create an answer

Comment: I have posted my Entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem,

As you can see in the mapper above, I am creating a new instance of `OrganisatonEntity` no matter what, even if it already exists !

So a small change in my code solved it:

```
public UserEntity map(UserInfo userInfo, OrganisationEntity organisationEntity);
```

instead of

```
public UserEntity map(UserInfo userInfo, Long orgaId);
```

When the organisation already exists, I then assign it to my `UserEntity` like such:

```
user.setOrganisation(organisationEntity);
```

instead of instantiating a new object.

Problem solved !