# Tooling that supports correct mapping of bidirectional JPA relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, static-code-analysis, tooling

I have multiple JPA (Hibernate) persisted @OneToMany and @OneToOne relationships in my project that are not held consistent by their setters and adders methods as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500921/5930295).
Now I need to refactor these relationships to programmatically keep consistency in place at all times.
Do static code analyses / generic unit tests or other tools exist to support me with this task?

Answer (score 0):

On my project we use integration spring tests with H2(Java SQL database).  It allows to find bugs even with relations between entities. There is a SpringRunner for JUnit which load application context so you can test your application almost as real environment. You can find more information here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html