# Duplicate entity for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

My problem that when I make cascade persist it throws exception (`MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`).
I am using `Spring Data;` for persisting my data.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry 'Bloomberg' for key 'PRIMARY'

News.class:

```
@Entity
public class News implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_name")
    private Company company;

    ...
}
```

Company.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true,nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<News> newsList;

   ...
}
```

I am using this code to persist :

```
public void parseDB() throws IOException {
    List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Company> companyMap = ((List<Company>) companyRepository.findAll()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Company::getName, company -> company));

    newsList.addAll(WebPagesParser.parseCategory("...", "...", companyMap));
    newsList.forEach(newsService::create);
    }


public static List<News> parseCategory(String url, String category,Map<String,Company> companyMap) throws IOException {
       ... 
      Company company; 
      if (companyMap.containsKey(name)) {
                    company = companyMap.get(name);
                } else {
                    company = new Company();
                    company.setName(top.get(1).text());
                }
       news.setCompany(company);
      ...
      }
```

And it gave me new exception

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached
>   entity passed to persist: com.example.inosmi.database.data.News;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached
>   entity passed to persist: com.example.inosmi.database.data.News

**Done:**
Have solved half of my problem, I still don't know where it is but it works. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You are trying to insert a row with a primary key which is already present in the database.

Comment: I want to MERGE  it, but it didn't.

Comment: Can u show us your query if you´re using one and your merging/persisting code?

Comment: You have to fetch the same entity from the database first and then update it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is telling you that you're trying to insert multiple rows with the same primary key

The code that this relates to is here

```
@Id
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;
```

And the data you're loading has multiple rows with the company name `Bloomberg`

Comment: I am completely understanding it, and I want it to merge this companies objects in one entity.

Comment: Then make sure you're loading the company object, not creating a new one. When you call `News#setCompany` the argument must be one that you've already loaded from the database, not one you just created with `new Company(...)`

Comment: And top result for Googling that error points to https://stackoverflow.com/q/13370221/134894

Answer (score 0):

Use Set instead of List for @OneToMany else maintain one `index` column

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "company",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<News> newsList;
```