# Detached entity passed error

Tags: jakarta-ee

here is my code.

```
@Entity 
public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private String isbn;
private String title;
private Double price;
@ManyToMany
List <Author> authors= new ArrayList<>();
```

Please what is the cause of this error ?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: library.Book
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
... 2 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA/Hibernate: detached entity passed to persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist)

Comment: @Ian Here is files of my project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8cuq8z6fh22sbhz/AAAFc1n7lgecqrrdsvfrtVrKa?dl=0    any help please ? i cant resolve the problem