# detached entity passed to persist: A class with ManyToOne relation to 2 more classes

Tags: jpa

1. Comment class

   ```
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User user;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
   private Image image;
   ```
2. User class

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = 
   FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
3. Image class

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "image",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = 
   FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
   ```
4. These are the ManyToOne and OneToMany relations I have. I am unable to persist the Comment object due to "detached entity passed to persist: ImageHoster.model.Comment" error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA/Hibernate: detached entity passed to persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist)

Comment: I have tried the changes suggested in the previous post but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. I kind of figured out the issue. In the CommentRepository class where I am persisting the Comment object, I used .merge instead of .persist

   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
   try{
       transaction.begin();
       em.merge(newComment);
2. instead of em.persist(newComment);