# Spring Data JPA: one-to-one instantiation problem: PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing a simple Order-Payment one-to-one association:

Order class relevant code:

```
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    (...)   

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="order")
    private Payment payment;
```

Payment class relevant code:

```
@Entity
public class Payment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId 
    private Order order;
```

Then I want to implement a basic method to seed my test database using Spring Data JPA repositories, but if I try the following code, I get a `PersistentObjectException` saying `detached entity passed to persist`:

```
Order o1 = new Order(null, Instant.parse("2019-06-20T19:53:07Z"));
orderRepository.save(o1);
Payment p1 = new Payment(null, Instant.parse("2019-06-23T13:02:55Z"), o1);
paymentRepository.save(p1);
```

Same problem happens if I try this way:

```
Order o1 = new Order(null, Instant.parse("2019-06-20T19:53:07Z"));
Payment p1 = new Payment(null, Instant.parse("2019-06-23T13:02:55Z"), o1);
orderRepository.save(o1);
paymentRepository.save(p1);
```

The only way it worked was as follows:

```
Order o1 = new Order(null, Instant.parse("2019-06-20T19:53:07Z"));
Payment p1 = new Payment(null, Instant.parse("2019-06-23T13:02:55Z"), o1);
o1.setPayment(p1);
orderRepository.save(o1);
paymentRepository.save(p1);
```

I'd like to understand why only the last approach works. In a many-to-one association I don't have to set that two-way association before saving in order to work. What am I missing about detached entities behavior this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because we have to set the Child Entity for Parent Entity as you have done using 
`o1.setPayment(p1);`

No need to pass the *id as null* as it will be `@GeneratedValue`. You may have to create an appropriate constructor for them.

As you are using `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` you may save the Parent and Child
as below *no need use save() for both entity*

```
//save Parent-Child at same 
        @PostMapping(value = "/onetoone")
        public String OneToOne(@RequestBody ParentOne parent)
        {
            ChildOne childOne = parent.getChildOne();
            childOne.setParentOne(parent);
            parent.setChildOne(childOne);
            parentOneRepository.save(parent);
            return "saved";

            /*{
                "parentName":"Parent Name",
                "childOne":{
                    "childName":"Child Name"
                }
            }*/
        }
```

[Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
Order o1 = new Order(null, Instant.parse("2019-06-20T19:53:07Z"));
Payment p1 = new Payment(null, Instant.parse("2019-06-23T13:02:55Z"), o1);
o1.setPayment(p1);
orderRepository.save(o1);
```

No need the save method for Payment. Because you used the cascade type like `@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="order")` Whenever you save the Order then Payment also saved.