# Detached entity passed to persist: JPA Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting below error in my application while trying to persist an object into database.

> nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.delivery.Message

**Entity:**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Getter @Setter @ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Message {

    @Id
    @Basic
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "MESSAGE_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MESSAGE_SEQ", sequenceName = "MESSAGE_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID")
    protected long messageId;

    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;
}
```

**DAO Layer:**

```
@Transactional
public void saveEntity(@Nullable T entity) {
    if (entity = null) {
        return;
    }

    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.detach(entity);
}
```

**Service Layer:**

```
public void saveMessage(HttpEntity<Message> entity) throws Exception{
    try{
        repository.saveEntity(entity);    
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
    
}
```

Not sure why am getting this error. Error is thrown at persist method. Any reason for this issue?

Comment: That generally means the ID is populated. When the ID is populated, the assumption is that the database record already exists and then you need to merge the data, not persist it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist thrown by JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-thrown-by-jpa-and-h)

Answer (score 0):

You should check is `messageId` filled in the received entity. Try this code:

```
if (entity.getId() == null) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
} else {
    entityManager.merge(entity);
}
```

You should use `Long` type instead of primitive `long` to allow identificator be null.