# What is best way to update CHILD entity while saving PARENT using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I have Building entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Building {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "building_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private int buildingId;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 255)
private String name;

@Column(name = "address", nullable = false, length = 255)
private String address;

@Column(name = "deleted", nullable = false)
private Boolean isDeleted = Boolean.FALSE;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "building", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private List<Floor> floorList;
}
```

And Floor entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Floor {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "floor_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private int floorId;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 255)
private String name;

@Column(name = "deleted")
private Boolean isDeleted = Boolean.FALSE;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "building_id")
private Building building;
}
```

So one `Building` has many `Floors` and i have trouble when inserting data in `Building` to update `building_id` in `Floor` entity (floor is populated table). This is example of my Building payload:

```
{
"name": "Some name",
"address": "Some address",
"floorList": [
    {
        "floorId": 1
    }
]   
}
```

I guess the problem can be cascading, but maybe i am completly wrong. So what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried various cascade types? I don't know much but I would try with `Cascade.ALL` and figure out if cascade is the problem or if there's anything else.

Comment: @ArunGowda Yes i did try `Cascade.ALL` but then i get `detached entity passed to persist` error

Comment: Did you check this one out? Setters on both the entities could be the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500921/8283737