# if CascadeType.ALL includes CascadeType.MERGE why detached entity passed to persist exception thrown only in CascadeType.ALL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a payment entity which have an `accountInvoice` field

```
public class Payment implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("payments")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private AccountInvoice accountInvoice;
}
```

When I try to save this payment entity with `CascadeType.ALL` `detached entity passed to persist` exception is being thrown but it works without any exception when  `CascadeType.MERGE` is used.If `CascadeType.ALL` includes `CascadeType.MERGE` why this behaviour?

Comment: please log the exception here

Comment: Is this your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-thrown-by-jpa-and-h