# Error at POSTing a register to a manyToOne relation with Spring Boot API

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa

I am using a @oneToMany - @manyToOne relationship in my entities but once I need to **save** a register to the @manyToOne side entity I get a 500 http code error. I've been looking for the mistake with no results since I think everything is ok with the code.

My POST request to "Factura".

```
{
"monto": 1002,
"persona":
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Test",
        "apellidoPaterno": "Testing",
        "apellidoMaterno": "Testing",
        "identificacion": "abc"
    }
 }
```

The response code:

```
{
"timestamp": "2022-06-20T18:46:44.318+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"path": "/factura"
}
```

And the error in VSC console.

```
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
detached entity passed to persist: com.test.gt.clientefactura.models.Persona;
```

Father entity (@oneToMany - Persona).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
public class Persona {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "persona_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nombre;    

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String apellidoPaterno;    
    
    private String apellidoMaterno;    

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String identificacion;

    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "fkPersonaId",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
        )
    private Set<Factura> facturas = new HashSet<>();
. . .
getters and setters
```

Child entity (@manyToOne - Factura).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "factura")
public class Factura {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
 private Long id;

 @CreationTimestamp
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
 private Date fecha;

 private float monto;

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "fkPersonaId", referencedColumnName = "persona_id")
 private Persona fkPersonaId;
. . .
getters and setters
```

The repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonaRepository extends CrudRepository<Persona, Long>{
    public Optional<Persona> findByIdentificacion(String identificacion);
    public long deleteByIdentificacion(String identificacion);
}

@Repository
public interface FacturaRepository extends CrudRepository<Factura, Long>{
    public abstract ArrayList<Factura> findAllByFkPersonaId(Long personaId);
}
```

The service class of the entity throwing the error (Factura).

```
@Service
public class Ventas {

  @Autowired
  FacturaRepository facturaRepository;

  public ArrayList<Factura> listFacturas() {
      return (ArrayList<Factura>) facturaRepository.findAll();
  }

  @Transactional
  public Factura storeFactura(Factura factura) {
      return facturaRepository.save(factura);
  }
. . .
```

And the controller code:

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/factura")
public class FacturaRestService {
    @Autowired
    private Ventas facturaService;

    @GetMapping
    public ArrayList<Factura> findFacturas() {
        return facturaService.listFacturas();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Factura addFactura(@RequestBody Factura factura) {
        return facturaService.storeFactura(factura);
    }
. . .
```

How can I save the register the way I want to? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I ran the app with the VSC debugger. The error I copied was from the VSC console. The error basically comes from the "Persona" class which is the father entity of the relation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using hibernate, you can use `merge` instead of `save`. But if that's not an option, may be below link will help you

[PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist thrown by JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-thrown-by-jpa-and-h)

PS: I could add comment below your question because of reputation points so posting it as an answer