# Spring boot Jackson JSON Parse Error : no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson, jackson-databind

My Connections Entity Model looks like this

```
@Entity
@Getter@Setter@AllArgsConstructor@NoArgsConstructor
public class Connections implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private MyUsers receiver;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private MyUsers sender;

    private boolean accepted

    private boolean following;
}
```

And my MyUsers Model entity class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "my_users")
public class MyUsers implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userName;

    private String password;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "myUsers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Blogs> blogs;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "receiver", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Connections> connections;
}
```

And the JSON POST Request Body to Connection API looks like this,

```
{
    "receiver": 1,
    "sender": 2,
    "following": 1,
    "accepted": 1
}
```

When I request I get this error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-07-18T17:24:47.330+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "trace": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `me.protik.simplyblog.models.MyUsers` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (9); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `me.protik.simplyblog.models.MyUsers` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (9)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 2, column: 17] (through reference chain: me.protik.simplyblog.models.Connections[\"receiver\"])\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:391)\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:343)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:185)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:160)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:133)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat me.protik.simplyblog.auth.filters.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:50)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `me.protik.simplyblog.models.MyUsers` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (9)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 2, column: 17] (through reference chain: me.protik.simplyblog.models.Connections[\"receiver\"])\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1728)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1353)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromInt(ValueInstantiator.java:324)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromInt(StdValueInstantiator.java:376)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromNumber(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1442)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:198)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:186)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:391)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:184)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3682)\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:380)\n\t... 95 more\n",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `me.protik.simplyblog.models.MyUsers` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (9); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `me.protik.simplyblog.models.MyUsers` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (9)\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 2, column: 17] (through reference chain: me.protik.simplyblog.models.Connections[\"receiver\"])",
    "path": "/user/connections/add"
}
```

only if I remove sender and receiver from JSON the API works.

All my entity classes contains getters and setters and constructors from Lombok and also user instance for user_id 1 and 2 exists in my MySQL db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send :
`{receiver: {id: 1}}` instead of `{receiver: 1}`,
This will create the user with only the id without breaking the rest

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, worked like a charm. Also while using this some error occurs for CascadeTyp.ALL, they should refer to this question in url or just use CascadeType.MERGE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-thrown-by-jpa-and-h

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON you are sending a number

```
"receiver": 1,
```

But in your entity class you expect the object

```
private MyUsers receiver;
```

There is no way to deserialize `1` to complex object.

If `1` and `2` are the IDs in the database and you hope that this will be magically deserialized - it's not how it works

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to JPA and Springboot, I thought this way at first but when I look at the database I see the references to user 1 and 2 are only saved in longlong type id's in the 'connection' table as JPA maps automatically so I thought I can only pass user id's to have a Foreign key like references to the user data table. What can solve my problem ?

Comment: Probably you are using hibernate and jackson. Hibaerante is an ORM and can use foreign keys from the database. But jackson is a simple json (de)serializer and is not connected to the database - can only map json string to the java class. Check this project, maybe it will help you https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest#overview https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Comment: I think the only thing that can work is a custom wrapper for jackson or wrapper that totally bypasses jackson and which resolves the object instance first from json request id no then serves the whole data as a connections instance and persists it. But this is advanced stuff for me, I have the idea, now I need to figure out the implementation if even possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question since I have just figured out a workaround, though far from an ideal design, it just works for now.

I added an extra class with other model class without annotating with **@Entity**(So JPA and Hibernate have nothing to do with it) and calling it **ConnectionsWrapper** (I don't know naming conventions well :| )

```
@Getter@Setter@AllArgsConstructor@NoArgsConstructor
public class ConnectionsWrapper implements Serializable {
    private Long receiver;
    private Long sender;
    private boolean accepted;
    private boolean following;
}
```

Then in the controller's **Add/Modify Connection API** I'm just parsing the **ConnectionWrapper** Class model type JSON using **@RequestBody** and then creating a new original **Connections** instance and setting datas using information from JSON request body of ConnectionWrapper type then saving the new Connections type Object in the database through Service and Repository functions.

```
@PostMapping("/user/connections/add")
    public void addModConnection(@RequestBody ConnectionsWrapper connectionsWrapper){
        Connections connection = new Connections();
        connection.setReceiver(myUsersService.showUserByIdService(connectionsWrapper.getReceiver()));
        connection.setSender(myUsersService.showUserByIdService(connectionsWrapper.getSender()));
        connection.setAccepted(connectionsWrapper.isAccepted());
        connection.setFollowing(connection.isFollowing());
        myUsersService.addModConnectionService(connection);
    }
```