# Persisting a parent with existing children throws detached entity exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this many-many relationship between students and courses as in following JPA models

```
@Entity(name = "course_result")
public class CourseResult {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Student.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Course.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Course course;
    private float grade;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;
    private String courseName;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<CourseResult> courseResult;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;
    private String studentName;
    private String studentClass;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<CourseResult> courseResult;
}
```

When persisting a CourseResult, I want a new course/student would be created if it not yet exists otherwise they'll be updated only. That's why I set the cascade type to ALL. T

However, it always throws an exception when I try to persist a new CourseResult with existing Student and Course, say both with Id = 1

```
    Student student = studentRepo.findById(BigInteger.ONE).get();
    Course course = courseRepo.findById(BigInteger.ONE).get();
    CourseResult courseResult = new CourseResult()
            .setCourse(course)
            .setStudent(student)
            .setGrade(1.5F);
    courseResultRepository.save(courseResult);
```

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: org.example.domain.Course; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.example.domain.Course
```

Do you have any idea why?

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you could try

1. Is there a Transaction around your Code ? It is not shown in your example. Ensure that the import is using the spring Transaction.
2. Try adding the courseResult to the other enities

   ```
   Student student = studentRepo.findById(BigInteger.ONE).get();
   Course course = courseRepo.findById(BigInteger.ONE).get();
   student.getCourseResult().add()
   CourseResult courseResult = new CourseResult()
       .setGrade(1.5F);
   student.getCourseResult().add(courseResult);
   course.getCourseResult().add(courseResult);
   ```
3. Try saving the CourseResult before adding it to the Objects. That way it might then be recognized by Hibernate as a managed entity

   ```
    Student student = studentRepo.findById(BigInteger.ONE).get();
    Course course = courseRepo.findById(BigInteger.ONE).get();
    student.getCourseResult().add()
    CourseResult courseResult = new CourseResult()
        .setGrade(1.5F);
    courseResultRepository.save(courseResult);
    courseResult.setStudent(student); 
    courseResult.setCourse(course); 
    courseResultRepository.save(courseResult);
   ```
4. Try adding

   ```
   cascade = CascadeType.ALL
   ```

   to

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<CourseResult> courseResult;
   ```

   and

   ```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CourseResult> courseResult;
   ```
5. Try using `cascade= CascadeTyp.Merge`insdead of `cascade= CascadeTyp.ALL` ([PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist thrown by JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-thrown-by-jpa-and-h))

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, it not yet works